# Average for large csv file

Tags: python, average, standard-deviation

suppose I have some data that looks like this:

```
time value
 1    1
 2    2
 3    3
 4    4
```

and it goes to 20,000, how would I get the average and stdev of this data?

```
1    import sys
2    import os
3    import string
4    import csv
5    import math
6    average = []
7    filename = 'pei1.rg'
8    fin1 = open(filename,"rb")
9    line1 = fin1.readline()
10   line1 = fin1.readline()
11   while line1:
12       line1 = map(string.strip,line1.strip().split())
13       average.append(float(line1[1]))
14       line1 = fin1.readline()
15   #print float(average)/float(count)
16   print "Number of steps: ", len(average)
17   print "Average over entire trajectory: ", float(sum(average))/float(len(average))
18   second = int(len(average)/2)
19   print "Average over second half: ", float(sum(average[second:]))/float(second)
20   sys.exit()
```

I think this works for calculating averages, but I do not know how to get the stdv from here.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code you have so far. If you haven't tried it yet, I would recommend reading the guidelines on questions on this site. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: i tried to post the code but it keeps telling me error code, I will try to post again. Sorry.

Comment: here is the code ive tried:

Comment: Do it by editing the question, not in a comment.

Comment: could you check now? I think this is better format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3 you can use the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) module, but first you need to arrange the values from your data into a sequence. Your data comes from a CSV file, so open the file, read in the lines, and convert the value to a float:

```
import statistics

with open('input.csv') as f:
    _ = next(f)    # skip the header line
    values = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in f]
    print('Average: {:.3f}'.format(statistics.mean(values)))
    print('Stdev: {:.3f}'.format(statistics.stdev(values)))
```

**Output**

Using the 4 values from your sample data:

```
Average: 2.500
Stdev: 1.291
```

It looks like you are using Python 2. There is a back port of the Python 3 statistics module for Python 2, and the above code will run without change. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statistics for info and install with `pip`.

Comment: thanks, I am trying this out now, pretty new to programming so I am working out some kinks

Comment: it worked! Thanks and it is much simpler than my code.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You might want to consider up-voting or even accepting this answer.

Comment: Done and done, however it says my upvote won't count until I've received 15 reputation. Hopefully it helped. Again, thanks!